# Jhipster entity change is causing liquibase checksum validation failed error

Tags: jhipster, liquibase, jhipster-registry

I am using H2 disk based persistance in my jhipster microservices application, After modifying the entity I am getting liquibase checksum validation error while building and starting server. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Have you read the doc about database updates? https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#using-a-database

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57902507/liquibase-checksum-validation-error-is-even-after-updating-changelog-in-master-x

Comment: Why opening 2 questions?