# liquibase checksum validation error is even after updating changelog in master.xml

Tags: jhipster, liquibase, jhipster-registry, liquibase-sql

I am using postgresql in jhipster microservices application. I am following jhipster documentation as below.

> Database updates with the Maven liquibase:diff goal If you have
>   choosen to use MySQL, MariaDB or PostgreSQL in development, you can
>   use the ./mvnw liquibase:diff goal to automatically generate a
>   changelog.
>
> If you are running H2 with disk-based persistence, this workflow is
>   not yet working perfectly, but you can start trying to use it (and
>   send us feedback!).
>
> Liquibase Hibernate is a Maven plugin that is configured in your
>   pom.xml, and is independant from your Spring application.yml file, so
>   if you have changed the default settings (for example, changed the
>   database password), you need to modify both files.
>
> Here is the development workflow:
>
> Modify your JPA entity (add a field, a relationship, etc.) Compile
>   your application (this works on the compiled Java code, so don’t
>   forget to compile!) Run ./mvnw liquibase:diff (or ./mvnw compile
>   liquibase:diff to compile before) A new “change log” is created in
>   your src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog directory Review
>   this change log and add it to your
>   src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml file, so it is applied
>   the next time you run your application

after updating an entity and following above document I have added generated changelog file in master.xml file.

```
<include file="config/liquibase/changelog//20190912080313_changelog.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
```

Still I am getting liquibase checksum validation error while running the application.Below is the screenshot
[image]

Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: It's not complaining about `20190912080313_changelog.xml` but about `20190912070733_added_entity_Blog.xml`.

Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995747/liquibase-checksum-validation-error-without-any-changes will help!

Comment: I have tried all the possible ways mentioned in the official document https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#using-a-database,  but still facing checksum validation error

Comment: I don't want to drop my table and regenerate it, I want to update an entity and table should be updated according to that without loosing any data.

Comment: Don't know what's different for you, it works for others. Anyway use a db client like DBeaver to connect to your db and try deleting the MD5SUM column for your changelog row in DATABASECHANGELOG table. Look at https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangelog_table.html

Comment: Also you said you have tried everything but I can't see any error in your question about each method you tried.